# Linq to SQl query extensions

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
query = query.Where(m => m.People.Contains(s)).Select(m => m).ToList();
```

In the above, "People" is an IList of strings. IF I replace People with a list of objects with string as a field of that object, how do I get the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
query = query.Where(m => m.People.Any(p => p.SomeProp == s)).ToList();
```